# Laravel Spark registration view not loading after fresh installation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-spark

I've just installed a fresh Spark app, went through the configuration instructions and set things up. My home view loads and so does the login view, however when I hit the registration route the view doesn't load. The header does, but there's no content. I tried:

- `php artisan cache:clear`
- `php artisan view:clear`
- `composer dumpautoload`
- `npm run dev`

**EDIT:**

I wanted to add some more information:

- Token set (verified with “spark token”)
- Composer 2.0
- Homestead / Vagrant
- Node v14.15.4
- npm v6.14.11
- Laravel Spark Installer 3.2.1
- Laravel Installer 4.1.1
- .env file includes my Stripe public and private keys (as suggested by this thread: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/spark/class-laravelsparkproviderssparkserviceprovider-not-found-1)
- Mac OS 10.13.6

I have other Spark projects in development that are running on the same VM and they all load fine. I'm not sure if this helps, but here is the require portion of my composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "laravel/spark-aurelius": "*@dev",
    "laravel/ui": "^2.0"
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was that I had my "live" Stripe keys in my `.env` file and not the "test" keys. Hope this helps someone out.